# How to give validation to a date filed in sugarcrm?

Tags: validation, sugarcrm

I created one module in that 2 dates are there like shipdate and delivery date.
I need to give validation for delivery date like if user enters a date before shipdate it will throws an error.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file 'record.js' in /custom/modules//clients/base/views/record/. In that file, you can add custom validation.

Some code you could use is:

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'YourModuleRecordView',
    initialize: function (options) {

        app.error.errorName2Keys['date_error'] = 'The Delivery date is before the shipdate.';

        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.model.addValidationTask('check_date', _.bind(this._doValidateDate, this));
    },
    _doValidateDate: function(fields, errors, callback) {
        if (strtotime(this.model.get('shipdate')) > strtotime(this.model.get('deliverydate'))) {
            errors['deliverydate'] = errors['deliverydate'] || {};
            errors['deliverydate'].date_error = true;
        }

        callback(null, fields, errors);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to change the fields names like you named them!
This result is only for edit mode. To add this validation to the creation mode, add the file 'create_actions.js' to /custom/modules//clients/base/views/create_actions/

Enter the folling code in your 'create_actions.js':

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'CreateActionsView',
    initialize: function (options) {

        app.error.errorName2Keys['date_error'] = 'The Delivery date is before the shipdate.';

        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.model.addValidationTask('check_date', _.bind(this._doValidateDate, this));
    },
    _doValidateDate: function(fields, errors, callback) {
        if (strtotime(this.model.get('shipdate')) > strtotime(this.model.get('deliverydate'))) {
            errors['deliverydate'] = errors['deliverydate'] || {};
            errors['deliverydate'].date_error = true;
        }

        callback(null, fields, errors);
    }
});
```

Perform a repair/rebuild when you added this files with the right code.
You can customize this code to your own needs.